# Xmldocument show value as value attribute in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

xmldocument generates all entry for me like below

```
<type>document</type>
```

i want it to generate like this

```
<type value = "document"></type>
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Just to add more details i have a json from which i am converting it to xml using JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode.

when i convert using this api , i get value like this -

```
<type>document</type>
```

i want it to be -

```
<type value = "document"></type>
```

Comment: How are you generating this? Are you using annotations (XmlAttribute, XmlElement) over a POCO object?

Comment: no i am not using annotaion its a simple property in POCO like below- public BundleType Type
        {
            get; set;
        }                            where Bundletype value is document

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the sample code to generate attribute.**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "type", "");
XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("value");
attr.Value = "Document";
node.Attributes.Append(attr);
doc.AppendChild(node);
var outputString = doc.InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the XML Linq Class for XML Creation. It is much easier to write and read.
You can bind it with "using System.Xml.Linq;"
Now you can create an Attribute in a Element with "new XAttribute".

Here is a small example:

```
        //build base
        XNamespace myNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XDocument myDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
            new XElement("newDocument",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", myNs),
                new XAttribute(myNs + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "ArchiveDocument.xsd"),
                new XElement("document",
                    new XAttribute("instanceDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")),
                    new XElement("attribute",
                        new XAttribute("attributeDefinitionId", "Belegart"),
                        new XElement("value", reportType)),
                    new XElement("attribute",
                        new XAttribute("attributeDefinitionId", "Date"),
                        new XElement("value", Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))),
                    new XElement("attribute",
                        new XAttribute("attributeDefinitionId", "Kalenderjahr"),
                        new XElement("value", Date.ToString("yyyy"))),
                    new XElement("attribute",
                        new XAttribute("attributeDefinitionId", "Kalendermonat"),
                        new XElement("value", Date.Month.ToString())),
                    new XElement("attribute",
                        new XAttribute("attributeDefinitionId", "Mitglieds_Nummer"),
                        new XElement("value", partnerId.ToString())))));
```